# How to create a video from a series of images with varying image durations?

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg

I'd like to programmatically create a video file that is composed of a series of images.  However, I'd also like to be able to specify a duration for each image.  I often see [ffmpeg examples](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images) suggested for similar tasks, but they always assume the same duration for each image.  Is there an efficient way to accomplish this?  (An inefficient solution might be setting the frame rate to something high and repeatedly copying each image until it matches the intended duration)

I will be dynamically generating each of the images as well, so if there is way to encode the image data into video frames without writing each image to disk, that's even better.  This, however, is not a requirement.

**Edit:** To be clear, I don't necessarily need to use ffmpeg.  Other free command-line tools are fine, as are video-processing libraries.  I'm just looking for a good solution.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve the exact same problem with the following commands.
vframes is set to the number of seconds * fps
In the example the first video has 100 frames (100 frame / 25 fps = 4 seconds) and second one has 200 frames (8 seconds)

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -loop 1 -vframes 100 -r 25 -i a.jpg -vcodec mpeg4 a.avi
ffmpeg -f image2 -loop 1 -vframes 200 -r 25 -i b.jpg -vcodec mpeg4 b.avi
mencoder -ovc copy -o out.mp4 a.mp4 b.mp4
```

The mencoder part is just like the one of d33pika

Comment: How can we do this without writing 60000+ videos to disk (if the video has that many frames)

Comment: always get 1 image per frame, no matter what options i set

Answer (score 5):

You can use the concat demuxer to manually order images and to provide a specific duration for each image.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -vsync vfr -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

> Your *input.txt* should look like this.

```
file '/path/to/dog.png'
duration 5
file '/path/to/cat.png'
duration 1
file '/path/to/rat.png'
duration 3
file '/path/to/tapeworm.png'
duration 2
file '/path/to/tapeworm.png'
```

*You can write this txt file dynamically according to your needs and excute the command.*

For more info refer to https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow

Comment: But how do you feed the files into ffmpeg in real time without having to write all of them to disk first

Comment: You might be having the urls of the images with you. For that case refer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49349684/10860783

Comment: But that's if all the pictures are made alreadyt, but how do you feed in the pictures as they are being made?

Comment: Can u please explain the real scenario? How the images are being made on command line? You might be using js or any other wrapper.

Comment: I have a c# program that is recording Images of a window, like a screen recorder. There is no fixed frame rate so it has to be in realtime like a screen recorder. Now I am able to save them all to disk with a time stack then generate the text for with the durations based on the time stamp for each one. But I don't want to write the instead the disk first, I want to pope then all in the ffmpeg in real time as they are being taken, each one with asl different duration. How can I do this

Comment: got error PTS -230584300921369, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0

Comment: Gives a currupt mp4

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there is no way to have different durations for different images using ffmpeg. I would create separate videos for each of the images and then concat them using mencoder like this:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -vframes 30 -i a.jpg -vcodec libx264 -r 1 a.mp4
ffmpeg -f image2 -vframmes 10 -i bjpg -vcodec libx264 -r 1 b.mp4
mencoder -ovc copy -o out.mp4 a.mp4 b.mp4
```

mencoder for the concat operation needs all the output videos to have same resolution,framerate and codec.

Here a.mp4 has 30 frames of duration 30 seconds and b.mp4 has 10 frames of 10 seconds.

Comment: I can't seem to apply frame rate property to the additional inputs.  I can set the frame rate (and therefore, duration) of the first input, but all the others seem to default to a framerate of 25.  Also, the start time of each of the inputs is 0.  I found the `-itsoffset` parameter, but I can't seem to set it for the successive inputs either.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have another solution now. I will edit the above answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay; I was on vacation. But I am still not getting this to work. `-vframes` seems to have no bearing on the number of frames in the individual output videos---each is one second long. Furthermore, the final output video (out.mp4) won't play, even in mplayer. It says there is a missing video stream, and that `LAVF_header: av_find_stream_info()` failed. But surely there must be a more efficient way to encode individual frames into a video. Is there a functional (and hopefully easy-to-use) library for Python or C that can accomplish this? Perhaps something like PIL, but for video?