# Creating timelapse video with ffmpeg using list of URL images from .txt file

Tags: image, url, ffmpeg, text-files, timelapse

I have pretty simple question.

Is it possible to render timelapse video using **ffmpeg**, from the list of **URL images** listed in **.txt** file?
(https://via.placeholder.com/350x150 -> image example)

This is how it works with the list of images from local disk:

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i input.txt output.mp4
```

If I replace locations of files in .txt file with URL addresses, it does not work. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343174/can-ffmpeg-concatenate-files-from-a-different-domain

Comment: Yes, adding -protocol_whitelist worked for me. Thank you.